# Getting an "Internal Error" message for a Google Earth Engine task that has run successfully before

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am running a code that I have run successfully hundreds of times before without a problem.  Now I am getting an "Internal Error" message.  I suspect it is a system problem, but am not sure.  The only difference is the polygons that I am exporting  for.  The input polygons seem fine, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
import ee
import gdal
import ogr
import geojson
import os, sys
import uuid

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

ee.Initialize()
myImage = ee.Image("users/myname/myasset")
myImageA = myImage.select(['b1'])
myImage60 = myImageA.updateMask(myImageA).gt(59).toByte()
mask = ee.FeatureCollection("users/myname/maskasset")

myImage60Clipped = myImage60.clip(mask)

shpfile = 'Mapping_Regions/myshapefile.shp'

drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
vecDS = drv.Open(shpfile, 0)
vecLyr = vecDS.GetLayer()
numQuads = vecLyr.GetFeatureCount()
print('Number of Quads: %d' % (numQuads))

for k,feat in enumerate(vecLyr):
    quadname = feat.GetField('QUADNAME')
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    gjson = geojson.loads(geom.ExportToJson())
    points = []
    for j in range(5):
        points.append([gjson['coordinates'][0][j][0], gjson['coordinates'][0][j][1]])
    myPoly = ee.Geometry.Polygon([points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], points[0]])

    task_config = {
        'folder': 'MyFolder',
        'scale': 9.554628534319960,
        'region': myPoly,
        'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
        'maxPixels': 1e13,
        'skipEmptyTiles': True,
        'fileFormat': 'GeoTiff',
        'formatOptions': { 'cloudOptimized': True }
        }

    task = ee.batch.Export.image(myImage60Clipped, quadname+'_gcrmn_reef_extent', task_config)
    task.start()
    print('%5d : %s : %s' % (k, quadname, task.id))

vecDS.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem!  The projection of the region that I was exporting was not in latitude/longitude (EPSG:4326).  GEE requires that, even though the image being exported is in a different projection.  It would be nice if GEE gave a more informative error, instead of "Internal Error".